# Gmail multiple inboxes cc and bcc mails not sorted in tab

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I had the multiple inboxes set-up in Gmail with the following pane:

```
to:myemail@gmail.com in:inbox
```

However, I noticed that e-mails not directed at me, but where my address was put in cc or bcc, would not arrive to this pane. So I added:

```
to:myemail@gmail.com OR cc:myemail@gmail.com OR bcc:myemail@gmail.com in:inbox
```

This did not work. The cc and bcc emails keep arriving in my inbox, but not in my separate inbox pane. I even set up separate panes, thinking maybe the OR operator did not work:

```
cc:myemail@gmail.com in:inbox
bcc:myemail@gmail.com in:inbox
```

No luck. Have not found a solution yet. What am I missing?

Comment: hace you tried it with "to:me OR cc:me or bcc:me in:inbox"      For me that makes it match exactly what is in my inbox